# recoding facebook timestamp in R

Tags: facebook, r

How do I recode of vector of timestamps from a facebook api pull that is a factored looking like the following to a time/date variable?

```
[[1] 2012-10-19T19:52:43+0000
```

I tried the following, but I only get NAs:

```
strptime(as.character(time), "%Y-%b-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is wrong.  The `%b` should be `%m`.

```
> strptime("2012-10-19T19:52:43+0000", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")
[1] "2012-10-19 19:52:43"
```